C# / ASP.NET MVC memory not releasing
I am working on an ASP.NET MVC application. I have a main page with a button that calls a controller method. In that part, the memory usage is 137 mb.
When I call the controller method, in that method I only add data to a list class in a for syntax for testing purpose.
public async Task<IActionResult> Search()
{
    List<SearchResultViewModel>? lstSearch = new();
    lstSearch = ParticipantSearch();

    GC.Collect();
    GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();

    return PartialView("Search");
}

private List<SearchResultViewModel>?  ParticipantSearch()
{
     List<SearchResultViewModel>? lstSearch = new();
     
     for (int i= 1; i< 100000; i++)
     {
         SearchResultViewModel search = new();
         search.ParticipantId = i;
         search.Relationship = "asd";
         search.CobraStatus = "asd";
         search.QualifyingEventType = "asd";
         search.FirstName = "asd";
         search.LastName = "asd";
         search.SocialSecurityNumber = "asd";
         search.ParticipantStatus = "asd";
         lstSearch.Add(search);
     }

     return lstSearch;
}

In that moment the memory rises to 174 mb...
I return null to the page...and the memory still is at 174 mb.
If I click the button again, it raises to 190 mb, and never goes down
Even if I call the garbage collector, nothing happens.
Why does the application continue to consume memory after the method finishes executing?

Are you really creating a list and doing nothing at all with it? Also I'm not an expert in memory management but it seems to me you are calling GC while the thing you want to destroy (lstSearch) is still in scope so I don't see that as being GC'd at that moment..

Firstly, you should make sure the increasing memory is related with your new creating objects, when the asp.net core MVC running, it may create a lot of other objects according to your application and these objects is still has the reference which makes the GC not collect it.
I have tested with your codes and it works well at my testing environment. You could find when I call the Search method, it will call the GC and you could check my captured snapshot, the List<SearchResultViewModel> inside the dead objects, which means it will be collected. You may wonder why these objects inside the dead objects not be collected after collect method,  you could check this answer.
My codes:
    public async Task<IActionResult> Search()
    {
        List<SearchResultViewModel>? lstSearch = new();
        lstSearch = ParticipantSearch();

        GC.Collect();
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();

        return PartialView("Search");
    }

    private List<SearchResultViewModel>? ParticipantSearch()
    {
        List<SearchResultViewModel>? lstSearch = new();

        for (int i = 1; i < 100000; i++)
        {
            SearchResultViewModel search = new();
            search.ParticipantId = i;
            search.Relationship = "asd";

            lstSearch.Add(search);
        }

        return lstSearch;
    }

Result:

All in all, the GC will work when it think it should work, no worry about it inside the testing environment, I suggest you could publish it and test it inside the production environment, then to see if its memory is always increasing or not.
More details about how GC works in .net , you could refer to this article.
